# Does proguard support GCM?

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, proguard

I receive this error when I try to rebuild app with proguard: (I tried all the solutions suggested for the error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1, but in my case, it seems have some conflicts with GCM )

> 19>PROGUARD : warning :
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find
>   referenced method 'void
>   setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)'
>   in class android.app.Notification 19>PROGUARD : warning :
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)'
>   in class android.app.Notification 19>        You should check if you
>   need to specify additional program jars. 19>PROGUARD : warning : there
>   were 2 unresolved references to program class members. 19>
>   Your input classes appear to be inconsistent. 19>           You may
>   need to recompile them and try again. 19>           Alternatively, you
>   may have to specify the option  19>
>   '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'. 19>  java.io.IOException:
>   Please correct the above warnings first. 19>     at
>   proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321) 19>     at
>   proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211) 19>     at
>   proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86) 19>     at
>   proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492) 19>  Picked up
>   JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 19>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2118,3):
>   error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Comment: I use Proguard (in `Xamarin.Android` projects) wth GCM and do not have a problem. I would assume it is the use of `setLatestEventInfo` in the error you posted as that is an older/deprecated method (assuming you are using it and targeting older APIs). The answer that was posted should help.

Answer (score 2):

The Google GMS libraries sometimes try to access library methods that are not available for a given target SDK version and gracefully handle errors at runtime. So it is usually required and safe to add something like this to ignore such warnings:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.**
```

These rules will ignore all warnings and notes from the gms libraries.

Comment: Afaik this should be the right place for a xamarin based application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this solution from Xamarin forum:

Create file named proguard.cfg inside Android project in the solution. Right click and set Build Action to ProguardConfig.
Add the following lines:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Amend the above according to type of errors you're getting
Make sure you save file as UTF-8 and NOT UTF-8 BOM

Compile version: 6.0
Min target: 5.1
Target version: 6.0